# Cross class reference between two child classes in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

How to make child class constructor from another child class in python3?

May be I need to make some class preinit import?
All classes is in one file, so I can't import it

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Parent"

class ChildOne(Parent):
    two = ChildTwo() # Not works!!! How to make it works???

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        two.print_two()

    def print_one(self):
        print "One"

class ChildTwo(Parent):
    one = ChildOne() # This works!!!

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        one.print_one()

    def print_two(self):
        print "Two"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this because you got recursion between child classes.
Only one way is to move this print_one and print_two to Parent Class and use it from parent.